# Overwrite parent class CSS with `!important` not working?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a navbar that I want to show up conditional upon the page. The place where it makes sense to incorporate this bar is after a div with className `content`. The attribute in content that I want to over-ride is `margin`.

I'd like to reuse the `navbar` class. I thought that if I added the line `margin: 0px 0px !important` that it would overwrite the desired attribute but it doesn't. I can only get the styling to do what I want if I comment out the `margin` from the `content` class.

```
/* css */
.content {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  padding: 20px;
}
.navbar {
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0px 0px !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
}
```

```
/* App.js */
function App() {
   return (
     <Router>
        <div className="App">
              <div className="navbar">
                     <NavLink
                     >Hello
                     </NavLink>
                     <NavLink
                     >World
                     </NavLink>
                </div>
            <div className="Content">
                <div className="navbar">
                     <NavLink
                     >Foo
                     </NavLink>
                     <NavLink
                     >Bar
                     </NavLink>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
   );
}
```

Comment: You get a top margin of 40px on the content dv because that is what you have asked the content class to do. Are you saying you get another 40px from the child navbar - I can't see how.

Comment: Okay, I'm pretty new to front-end so maybe I don't understand how the inheritance stuff works. What you're saying is after the div has been declared,  I can't tell the subsequent class to ignore that element which is what I'm trying to do. I didn't realize that's what I was doing but makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: You would need to set some sort of condition that dynamically changes the margin style because the content margin is coupled to the content element and same with nav. Changing the margin on nav will have no effect on content and vice versa. You can achieve what you are attempting to do through shared state e.g. if active === true, then content margin: 0; and nav: margin: 40px, and vice versa is active === false; You do this will CSS of React / Vue inline styles components.

Comment: That's a good way to do it. I might go back and try doing it that way, I just distributed the content class into the places I wanted it as a work around